# iOS WKWebView handle input file image

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, wkwebview

When use WKWebView to load HTML page, that contains a image file upload input like bellow:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

How can I handle this input action in iOS native app?

I want to add some filter before upload selected image to webview.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?